# Creating place holder text in Excel

Tags: excel

I'm still fairly new to excel but I can just about work out some simple formulas. I'm looking to create a placeholder text effect. The way I want to achieve this is like so;

Cell A1 : has the place holder text and is hidden.
Below this, cell B1 containing the formula.

This formula checks to see if Cell C1 is blank if C1 is blank it returns a value to C1. That value being the value of A1.

This is what I have in my head but I'm unsure on how to code this. I have bounced around the web for a while but I can't find a specific answer. The closest I have gotten is;

```
=IF(C6<>"","",C4)
```

Just to clarify Im looking to oput the result of formula B1 into C1.

Comment: I don't understand the reason for B1. Also, for what reason is C1 blank?  It would seem as though you need to simply handle it all in C1, where you check if whatever is already in C1 would return blank, and if so, return A1

Comment: C1 is an empty cell I want it to read [Text] When it is empty. to do this I need to repeat the value of another cell into C1.

Comment: Defining the formula in C1 only creates a cuircular, hense the reason for pushing the value through a third cell via a formula.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data of what your input and expected output would be?

Comment: Input would be "" (Nothing.) The output would be to copy one cell and place it in another. I'm not sure how much simpler I can word it.  :)

Comment: OK, well you can't copy one cell to another with a formula, that would require VBA. Is C1, C2 etc.. always blank?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105710/discussion-between-null-and-click-here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so put this in the worksheet's code module. Make sure you put it in the module for the *specific* sheet you're monitoring.

[image]

First, fill your range C5 through C99 with the formula like `=$C$1`. You should only need to do this one time, the macro will take care of it later.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

'the formula reference
Dim defaultFormula As String
defaultFormula = "=$C$1"

'The default text cell:
Dim defaultText As Range
Set defaultText = Range("C1")

'The cells you want to monitor:
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("C5:C999") '## Modify as needed

'Cell iterator
Dim cl As Range

If Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

'Avoid infinite looping
Application.EnableEvents = False

'If the user has deleted the value in the cell, then replace it with the formula:
For Each cl In Intersect(Target, rng)
    If Trim(cl.Value) = vbNullString Then
        cl.Formula = defaultFormula
    End If
Next

'Turn on Events:
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

What this does is (hopefully) pretty self-explanatory from the comments in the above code The `Change` event is raised any time a cell on the worksheet is *changed*.

Comment: Slight issue has come around, please see chat.>

Comment: Sorry to open this can of worms back up but im experienceing some issues with this solution. it appears to only work for the frist 10 seconds or so that excel is open. After which it seases to function.

Comment: Unless you're getting an error/warning message (I made small revision to answer above to hopefully handle that), there is nothing in this code that has any sort of "conditional" that would restrict the event procedure from raising, *each* time the event occurs.

Comment: I am getting an error when the text doesnt match the original default cell. However, the revised version of your code is failing to work  at all :(

Comment: Without knowing what you did to break it, I can't really help you. Please post the full code in a revised version of your question, above.  It is possible that, if there was an error in the previous version, that Events have been disabled. You may need to turn them back on manually using `Application.EnableEvents = True` in the VBE Immediate pane.

Comment: Also, elaborate on what is meant by "when the text doesn't match the original default cell".  That sentence literally makes no sense at all. There is no criteria in this code for any sort of "matching" or equivalence. We're simply testing for an empty value, and if the value is empty, then we replace it with a formula pointing to $C$1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105723/discussion-between-null-and-david-zemens).

Comment: Not available to chat ATM. Since this actually did solve the problem, what it seems like is that you now have a *new* problem, and probably you should be asking a *new* question with specific details for this particular problem you're now facing.

Comment: I'll link you to these it will help you understand. (http://i.stack.imgur.com/riTIT.png), (http://i.stack.imgur.com/dP6Jq.png). I have made no adjstments to your original code other than tweaking the comments to more easily understand at a later date. In regards to the error I stated as stated by excel. Sorry if it was confusing.

Comment: That's not an error, just a warning. and you can safely ignore it (unless you require the formulas be consistent, in which case you either need to modify the one used in the Macro, or the one used elsewhere in the column). If "nothing" is happening when you delete cell value in that range, then that suggests Events have been disabled somehow, and you may need to manually re-enable them as mentioned above. Then, ensure you're using the revised answer, you're missing a few lines.